# UNION ALL results are not sorted properly

Tags: mysql, union-all

It is necessary to make a complex selection from the table with sorting for different conditions. When I make two requests separately, then everything works, and if I combine, it outputs without sorting - by the growth of the key field of the table

```
(SELECT * 
 FROM `user` 
 WHERE `user`.`rank_golos` >=22.1 
 order by `user`.rank_yearnub DESC, `user`.rank_golos DESC) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT * 
 FROM `user` 
 WHERE `user`.`rank_golos` <22.1 and `user`.`rank_golos` >0 
 order by `user`.rank_golos DESC, `user`.rank_yearnub DESC)
```

Comment: Can you show the result you're expecting?

Comment: Those. give an example of a table?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`union all` outputs the results of each query serially - your rows would be ordered *within each query result* but not overall.

To effect an overall ordering, move the `order by` *outside* the two queries by creating an outer query to wrap the `union all` result.

To effect ordering that's different depending on which half of the `union all` the result came from, add information to the rows about the source of the row and use that to get the specific ordering:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 1 as source 
    FROM `user` 
    WHERE `user`.rank_golos >= 22.1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT *, 2
    FROM `user` 
    WHERE `user`.rank_golos < 22.1 and `user`.rank_golos > 0
) x
order by
  case when source = 1 then rank_yearnub else rank_golos end DESC,
  case when source = 1 then rank_golos else rank_yearnub end DESC
```

If you need to exclude `source` from the query output, you could wrap the above and another outer query that just selects all columns *other* than `source`.

I've also removed the unnecessary brackets.

Comment: But he wants to order the two groups differently. Can you show how to do that outside the subqueries?

Comment: Your ordering is not correct. The first group is supposed to be `ORDER BY rank_yearnub DESC, rank_golos DESC`.

Comment: @Barmar skimmed it. Got it now though :)

Comment: But i have error
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM `user` WHERE `user`.rank_golos >= 22.1 UNION ALL ' at line 2

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: Working. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
select * from user
where rank_golos >0
order by rank_golos >=22.1 desc, 
  if (rank_golos >=22.1, rank_yearnub, rank_golos) desc,
  if (rank_golos >=22.1, rank_golos, rank_yearnub) desc
```